# java.lang.StackOverflowError: null when serializing an object using gson

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization, polymorphism, gson

I am trying to serialize an object to a json file using gson, this is the object class:

```
public class EventSetMetaData {

    private ArrayList<Feature> featureMap;

    }
```

for featureMap list, there are 2 types of features, first one is original feature:

```
public class Feature {

    private String featureName;
    private NormalizationType normalization;
    private boolean isSelected;
    private Normalizer normalizer;

    public Feature(String featureName) {
        this.featureName = featureName;
        isSelected = true;
        this.normalization = NormalizationType.NOT_SET;
        this.normalizer = null;
    }
```

and it could be CategoricalFeature which extends Feature class:

```
public class CategoricalFeature  extends Feature {  

    private ArrayList <String> categories;

    public CategoricalFeature(String featureName, ArrayList<String> categories) {
        super(featureName);
        this.categories = categories;
    }
```

I was trying to use customized adapter I found online to solve the different type issue, this is the implementation of that class:

```
public class InterfaceAdapter<T>
    implements JsonSerializer<T>, JsonDeserializer<T> {

    @Override
    public final JsonElement serialize(final T object, final Type interfaceType, final JsonSerializationContext context) 
    {
        final JsonObject member = new JsonObject();

        member.addProperty("type", object.getClass().getName());

        member.add("data", context.serialize(object));

        return member;
    }

    @Override
    public final T deserialize(final JsonElement elem, final Type interfaceType, final JsonDeserializationContext context) 
            throws JsonParseException 
    {
        final JsonObject member = (JsonObject) elem;
        final JsonElement typeString = get(member, "type");
        final JsonElement data = get(member, "data");
        final Type actualType = typeForName(typeString);

        return context.deserialize(data, actualType);
    }

    private Type typeForName(final JsonElement typeElem) 
    {
        try 
        {
            return Class.forName(typeElem.getAsString());
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            throw new JsonParseException(e);
        }
    }

    private JsonElement get(final JsonObject wrapper, final String memberName) 
    {
        final JsonElement elem = wrapper.get(memberName);

        if (elem == null) 
        {
            throw new JsonParseException(
                "no '" + memberName + "' member found in json file.");
        }
        return elem;
    }

}
```

and this is the code im using to serialize the object:

```
 GsonBuilder gsonBilder = new GsonBuilder();
             gsonBilder.registerTypeAdapter(CategoricalFeature.class, new InterfaceAdapter<CategoricalFeature>());

  gsonBilder.setPrettyPrinting();

    gson =gsonBilder.create();
    f = new FileWriter("MetaData.json");
    gson.toJson(eventSetMetaData, f);
    f.close();
```

the exception I got is:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.push(JsonWriter.java:354)
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.<init>(JsonWriter.java:170)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.JsonTreeWriter.<init>(JsonTreeWriter.java:58)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJsonTree(Gson.java:492)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJsonTree(Gson.java:472)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$2.serialize(Gson.java:134)
    at com.tts.tts_rta_ai_stream_processor_plugin.api.utils.InterfaceAdapter.serialize(InterfaceAdapter.java:23)
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.write(TreeTypeAdapter.java:70)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:600)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJsonTree(Gson.java:493)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJsonTree(Gson.java:472)
    at com.google.gson.Gson$2.serialize(Gson.java:134)
```

In feature class, normalizationType is enum, there is nothing in normalizer right now, Any Ideas how can i solve this problem? Thank you inadvance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

How have you created `eventSetMetaData`? I would hazard a guess that you never initialized it or similar and therefore it is a null reference.

In your serialize code Instead of using the `EventSetMetaData` class why not just use the ArrayList directly?

Here is a simple working example that you can slot right into your code. It uses the ArrayList directly without being nested in the EventSetMetaData class:

```
//Array list used to store Features for JSON
ArrayList<Feature> featureMap = new ArrayList<>();
//Add items to ArrayList
featureMap.add(new Feature("Example Feature One"));
featureMap.add(new Feature("A different feature"));

//Create GsonBuilder and set options
GsonBuilder gsonBilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBilder.registerTypeAdapter(CategoricalFeature.class, new InterfaceAdapter<CategoricalFeature>());
gsonBilder.setPrettyPrinting();

//Create Gson object
Gson gson =gsonBilder.create();

//Create file Writer
Writer f = new FileWriter("MetaData.json");

//Save featureMap ArrayList to file
gson.toJson(featureMap, f);

//Tidy up
f.close();
```

And the output in `MetaData.json` looks like (Obviously it is stripped down because I don't know the `normalizationType` enum):

```
[   
  {
    "featureName": "Example Feature One",
    "isSelected": true   
  },   
  {
    "featureName": "A different feature",
    "isSelected": true   
  } 
]
```